# Deleting / renaming a network hardware port in OS X / Darwin

Tags: networking, osx, network-interface, darwin

There's a problem with a device being listed twice with the same hardware port name which is causing a lot of trouble since the OS X configuration utilities (both GUI *System Preferences* and command-line tool `networksetup`) rely on the method `SCNetworkInterfaceRef
_SCNetworkInterfaceCreateWithEntity` which tries to get an interface by its name but bails if the array `matching_interfaces` contains more than one device.

Issuing `networksetup -listallhardwareports` returns the following output:

```
Hardware Port: H5321 gw
Device: usbmodem
Ethernet Address: N/A

Hardware Port: H5321 gw
Device: usbmodem
Ethernet Address: N/A

Hardware Port: PCI Serial Adapter (22)
Device: pci-serial22
Ethernet Address: N/A

Hardware Port: H5321 gw
Device: wwan
Ethernet Address: N/A

Hardware Port: Ethernet
Device: en0
Ethernet Address: 28:d2:44:05:79:1c

Hardware Port: H5321 gw
Device: en1
Ethernet Address: 02:15:e0:ec:01:00

Hardware Port: 802.11n WLAN Adapter
Device: en2
Ethernet Address: 00:87:23:7a:44:9d

Hardware Port: Bluetooth PAN
Device: en3
Ethernet Address: f4:b7:e2:e8:4f:78
```

The culprit in this case is the interface `usbmodem`. While

`ls /dev | grep usbmodem`

lists the two entities by seperate names (the number of the second one changes upon restart)

```
cu.usbmodem
cu.usbmodem5
tty.usbmodem
tty.usbmodem5
```

the network setup utility is pointing out the problem - the same hardware port name being used twice.

All methods which rely on [`configd`'s implementation](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/configd/configd-801.10.2/SystemConfiguration.fproj/SCNetworkInterface.c) fail appending the message

```
more than one interface matches usbmodem
```

to the system log, which is why I can't use my WWAN modem.

I think having a way to rename / delete the second hardware port name might solve the problem but I don't know enough about the underlying implementations - I don't know which file or service is responsible for creating the hardware port list in the first place but maybe one of the *NIX gurus know anything about that, taking into consideration that OS X shares part of its code base with BSD.

Comment: I think it's a gray area when you're talking command line.  `networksetup` is not a standard BSD command but Darwin is a BSD.  Not sure if there's a hard rule.

Comment: @DougHendrick The "on-topic" list says questions about "[t]he Unix foundation underlying OS X (but generally not frontend application questions)" are okay, so I hope this isn't OT... but I think since the program causing the problems is part of the open-source foundation of OS X, it's OK. The folks at Apple.SE didn't seem to know anything about this anyway. In fact, there's NO Google match about OS X for the exact string "more than one interface matches" apart from the Apple source so I guess I'll need to ask it SOMEwhere... but then again, might SuperUser or StackOverflow be more appropriate?

Answer (score 0):

```
networksetup -renamenetworkservice "usbmodem" "new-name"
```

does the job. It renames the first of the two services. If that was wrong, you can rename again.